# Fixed width table cell

Tags: html

I'm trying to make cells have a fixed (in px) width within a table.

This is what I have now:

```
        <table style="border: 1px solid black; width: 1128px; table-layout: fixed;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red; width: 4px;">Row 1 Col 1</td>
                <td style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red; width: 4px;">Row 1 Col 2</td>
                <td style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red; width: 4px;">Row 1 Col 3</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

However, none of the table-cells are 4px wide. What am I missing?

Comment: Well you did specify the table width as 1128px.

Comment: Yes the table width is correct, what I want is to make cells have 4px of width

Comment: It doesn't work like that, Vitor.  The table consists of its cells, so having a 1128px-wide table filled only 12px wide doesn't make sense.  You might want to wrap your table in a div that's 1128px wide instead.  Or maybe you want to use `max-width` instead of `width` for the table width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a 4th `<td>` tag, with no width specified:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black; width: 1128px; table-layout: fixed;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red; width: 4px;">Row 1 Col 1</td>
            <td style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red; width: 4px;">Row 1 Col 2</td>
            <td style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red; width: 4px;">Row 1 Col 3</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zESk5/). The width of the first three cells is 4px, and the 4th, empty cell fills up the remaining width of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add buffer cells...

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YGRGG/

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Row 1 Col 1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Row 1 Col 2</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Row 1 Col 3</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 1128px;
}
table td:nth-of-type(2),
table td:nth-of-type(4),
table td:nth-of-type(6) {
    width:4px;
}
```